# createRef as prop to createElement

Tags: reactjs, createelement

I'm new to React and its processes.  How would I add a ref to an element as a prop?  So far I am getting null for ref, and undefined for wordRef.

```
render(){
const { 
  str = "Functional components cannot leverage on the performance improvements and render optimizations that come with React.",
  func = function(){
    const words = str.split(" ");
    const els = words.map( word => {
      const ref = React.createRef();
      console.log('ref',ref.current); // null

      return React.createElement( "wrd", {attr:"ref-"+ref}, word+" ");
    });
    return els;
  },
  wordRef = React.createRef()
} = this.props;
```

Comment: If you are new to react you shouldn't be using `createRef` or `createElement`, which is considered a really bad practice. Where are you learning react ?

Comment: @Treycos, I'm open to suggestions. This is a personal exercise. The goal is to find two overlapping DOM elements in componentDidMount. I need to run through the nodes and find the one overlapping another DOM element (say... of className="magicLantern"). findDOMNode is deprecated, and React documentation suggests createRef is the way to go. Would you have suggestions to identify the overlapping item?

Answer (score 0):

You have some ways in order to create a ref. This is one:

Class components:

```
class AutoFocusTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <input
       type="text"
       ref={this.textInput} />
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to pass this ref as prop, you need to create the child component as class.

Function Components:

```
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  // textInput must be declared here so the ref can refer to it
  let textInput = React.createRef();

  function handleClick() {
    textInput.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={textInput} />

      <input
        type="button"
        value="Focus the text input"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Documentation is useful and you can see how to create a ref properly: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

However, take care using ref:  "Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively."

Comment: Thanks.  To your point, and React's: "There are a few good use cases for refs: Managing focus, text selection, or media playback. Triggering imperative animations. Integrating with third-party DOM libraries."  That being said I only sought createRef as a solution because React suggested it as the replacement of the now deprecated findDOMNode. Is the better solution for me to simply generate my own ref by way of an index number, {ref:"ref-"+index}?